# use ratio as dependent variable in glmm

Tags: proportion, glmm, predictor, ratio

I have a dataset I am working with to model the proportion of fish caught at length conditioned on the total catch at length.  I have paired observations (n=96).  The paired observations consist of a 10 minute tow and a 15 minute tow.  Data collected are length measurements in 1 mm intervals, number of fish at length, and total catch (number of baskets) for each tow.

total_catch_a is the number of baskets caught for the A tow
total_catch_b is the number of baskets caught for the B tow

The traditional approach to model this type of data is to use a logistic regression to model the proportion caught at length in the 10 min to the total catch at length in both tows in a pair and then have the pair as the random effect.  Traditional fixed effects are length and length^2.

length is the length of a fish and length^2 is the square root of the length
both length and length^2 are scaled in the model for convergence

I would like to include total catch in the model, but am struggling with how to include the variable because there is a total catch record for each tow.
I was hoping for some guidance on if it is appropriate to include total catch for both tows or for one of the tows, if total catch between both tows is correlated as a continuous variable.  Or could a ratio of total catches be used as a independent variable.

General model:
prop = number at length 10 min tow (B)/(number at length 10 min tow+number at length 15 min tow (A))

```
 mm2<-glmer(prop~1+length+length^2+(1|id),weights=total,offset=offst,data=datae,family="binomial")
```

I tried adding in two more independent variables for catch 
     mm3<-glmer(prop~1+length+length^2+total_catch_a+total_catch+b+(1|id),weights=total,offset=offst,data=datae,family="binomial")

The coefficients for the two total catch terms have different signs but the same effect size - for example total_catch_a = 0.5 and total_catch_b  = -0.5.  This doesnt make sense to me.  It almost seems like they are canceling each other out.

The other option I thought of was to have the ratio of total_catch_b/total_catch_a as a predictor variable.  I have never used a ratio as a independent variable nor have I seen one used so do not know if it is appropriate.

An example data set is:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand the variable. A "length" describes the length of time for a "tow": a single fishing trip. Are you saying you are modeling the fraction of netted or trolled material that happens to be fish as opposed to other matter like debris. Is that right? Is this quantity in units of kgs or similar?

Comment: I added a definition of length  - its the length of a fish in mm.  total catch is in number of baskets.  I'm modelling the number of fish at a given length compared to the total catch from both gears at that same length as a function of length and length^2

Comment: Are the data then one row per fish or one row per basket or one row per tow?

Comment: data are 1 row per proportion of fish with corresponding length, length^2 and catch data.  I added a small example dataset.  id is the pair and the random effect.